# Paramiko can connect with multiple passwords.

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I was seeing this inconsistency where paramiko was able to connect to the same host with same username 'april' with 2 different passwords. My guess is it has saved the host/username combination on known_hosts. I have deleted my ~/.ssh/known_hosts file but still see the same. How to go about it ?

```
    >>> import paramiko
    >>> ssh = paramiko.SSH_Client()
    >>> ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    >>> ssh.connect(hostname="XX.XXX.XX.120", username="april", password="passwd")
    >>> ssh.close()
    >>> ssh.connect(hostname="XX.XXX.XX.120", username="april", password="diff_passwd")
    >>> ssh.close()
```

Comment: My guess would be that it's not using the passwords because you have some other auth mechanism, like `authorized_keys`, that takes precedence over password when you don't specify which one you want.

Comment: If that's the problem, you need to delete (or edit) `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server side. Deleting `~/.ssh/known_hosts` on the client side has nothing to do with the server authenticating the user, it has to do with the client authenticating the server. (If the server is found in `known_hosts`, and its cert doesn't match the known cert, the client will warn you and/or refuse to connect. Using `AutoAddPolicy` means that if the server _isn't_ found in `known_hosts`, the client just assumes that its cert is correct and remembers it for later.)

Answer (score 0):

Adding look_for_keys=False to the connect hostname resolved my issue, however, I would still like to understand how the remote connection was getting setup earlier.